# Showing sonarqube error for normal if..else statement in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Getting sonarqube error for the below code. I have tried with different approaches but still getting the same error.

**Approach 1:**

```
let titleHeader;
if (mobileDevice) {
  titleHeader = "h5";
} else {
  titleHeader = "h4";
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
let titleHeader: any = "h4";
if (mobileDevice) {
  titleHeader = "h5";
}
```

And I am using the variable in

```
<Typography variant={titleHeader}>Title</Typography>
```

Also I tried with the ternary operator the Typography tag itself, but getting the same error.

[image]

Comment: What error specifically?

Comment: Error screenshot attached now.

Comment: can you see an error description?? probably hover over the if condition?

Comment: Not showing any hint. :(

Comment: https://blog.devgenius.io/sonarqube-cognitive-complexity-265640dbad3e